# Confusing notation of sequences in $k$-dimensional Euclidean spaces.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Suppose $(x^{(n)})$ is a sequence in $\mathbb R^k$, $k \in \mathbb N$. From what I understand, $(x^{(n)})$ is a sequence of sequences $(x_1^{(n)}, x_2^{(n)}, x_3^{(n)}, ..., x_k^{(n)})$. Or in other words, $(x_j^{(n)})$ are *terms* of the sequence $(x^{(n)})$ for $j \in \mathbb N, 1\le j \le k$.

By the definition of a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb R^k$, if $\epsilon \gt 0$, there exists $N$, such that
$$m,n \gt N \implies d(x^{(m)}, x^{(n)}) \lt \epsilon$$
If $(x_j^{(n)})$ are terms of the sequence $(x^{(n)})$, then what is $(x^{(m)})$? By the definition of a cauchy sequence in $\mathbb R$, which is that if $\epsilon \gt 0$, there exists $N$, such that
$$m,n > N \implies |s_n-s_m| < \epsilon$$
In this case, $s_m$ is a term in the sequence $s_n$, so that should mean that $(x^{(m)})$ too is a term of $(x^{(n)})$. But aren't $(x_1^{(n)}, x_2^{(n)}, x_3^{(n)}, ..., x_k^{(n)})$ the terms of $(x^{(n)})$? I realise that this question is stupid, but I doubt I'm gonna be able to study further on this topic unless I clear this up. Thank you for your time.

Edit: I am defining $d(x,y)$ as follows-
$$d(x,y) = \left[\sum_{j=1}^k(x_j-y_j)^2\right]^{\frac{1}{2}} \text{ for } x,y \in \mathbb R^k$$

Comment: $x^{(m)}$ is the mth sequence.  How are you defining $d$, the distance between two sequences?

Comment: What is the distance you are considering on $\mathbb{R}^k$?

Comment: 1) Your sequence should be denoted $(x^{(n)})_{n\in\Bbb N},$ or $(x^{(n)})$ for short. Not just $x^{(n)}$. 2) You are right in saying it is a sequence of sequences. More precisely, it is an infinite sequence of finite  (of length $k$) sequences. 3) It might be a good exercise for you to prove that this sequence is Cauchy (in $\Bbb R^k$) iff the $k$ sequences $(x^{(n)}_j)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ ($j=1,\dots,k$) are Cauchy (in $\Bbb R$).

Comment: @AnneBauval I still don't understand what $(x^{(m)})$ is though. Is $(x^{(n)})$ related to $(x^{(m)})$(as in, are they the same sequence), or are they different sequences?

Comment: It should be clearer with the full notation $(x^{(n)})_{n\in\Bbb N}$ for this (unique) sequence that the letter $n$ is a dummy variable and can be replace by any letter. For any integer $r,$ $x^{(r)}\in\Bbb R^k$ is the $r$-th term of this sequence.

Answer (score 1):

A sequence in $\mathbb{R}^k$ is not a sequence of sequences, it is a sequence of vectors. Usually, when we speak of sequences, it is implied that they have an infinite number of terms. In your definition of a Cauchy sequence, both $x^{(n)}$ and $x^{(m)}$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^k$, and $d(x^{(n)}, x^{(m)})$ is a real number, given, in the case of the Euclidean instance, by
$$
d(x^{(n)},x^{(m)}) = \left(\sum_{j=1}^k(x^{(n)}_j-x^{(m)}_j)^2 \right)^{1/2}.
$$

Since in finite dimensional spaces all norms are equivalent, you can also use distances like

$$
d(x^{(n)},x^{(m)}) = \sum_{j=1}^k|x^{(n)}_j-x^{(m)}_j|
$$

or

$$
d(x^{(n)},x^{(m)}) = \max_{j=1, \cdots, k}|x^{(n)}_j-x^{(m)}_j|.
$$

Comment: So to clarify, we can view $x^{(n)}$ as a vector in a k-dimensional euclidean space, made up of constituent vectors $(x_1^{(n)}, x_2^{(n)}, x_3^{(n)}, ..., x_k^{(n)})$, and $x^{(m)}$ is just another vector in that k-dimensional space?

Comment: No... $x^{(n)}$ is a vector in a $k$-dimensional space, made up of constituent **real numbers** $x_j^{(n)}, j = 1, \cdots, k$. The vector $x^{(m)}$ is just another element of the sequence and has the exact same nature.